# Javascript / CSS tabs with fade effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve tabs that when we change from one to another they fade between.
The piece of code I'm using works but there is one problem.
When I come from the next tab to the previous one, there's a glitch where I can see for one second the last tab changing state before fading.

The HTML:

```js
function openSvc(evt, svc) {
  var i, x, tablinks, opacitys;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("svc");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.remove('display-yes');
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(svc).classList.add('display-yes');
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.svc {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
}

.display-yes {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openSvc(event,'dev')"> Desenvolvimento de software </button>
  <button class="tablink active" onclick="openSvc(event,'it')"> Infraestruturas IT </button>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openSvc(event,'design')"> UX / UI Design </button>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openSvc(event,'consult')"> Consultoria </button>
</div>

<div id="dev" class="svc display-yes">
  <p>lorem ipsum1

</div>

<div id="it" class="svc">
  <p>lorem ipsum2
</div>
<div id="design" class="svc">
  <p>lorem ipsum3

</div>

<div id="consult" class="svc">
  <p>lorem ipsum4

</div>
```

The example : https://jsfiddle.net/4fz01c2o/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `transition` might be set on `.display-yes` : https://jsfiddle.net/6L9csvmw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what effect you're looking for here.
G-Cyrillus' solution works but it seems like you lose a bit the fade effect.

So, to keep that effect, you need to remove the `position: relative` rule that was applied on `.display-yes`.

It was messing with the div's position. For that matter you need to add a `position: relative;` container to keep the `.svc` divs in place.

```js
function openSvc(evt, svc) {
  var i, x, tablinks, opacitys;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("svc");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.remove('display-yes');
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(svc).classList.add('display-yes');
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.svc-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.svc {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}

.svc p {
  margin: 0; /* To be consistent with the next block*/
}

.display-yes {
  opacity: 1;
}

.tablink {
  background-color: blue;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablink active" onclick="openSvc(event,'dev')"> Desenvolvimento de software </button>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openSvc(event,'it')"> Infraestruturas IT </button>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openSvc(event,'design')"> UX / UI Design </button>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openSvc(event,'consult')"> Consultoria </button>
</div>
<div class="svc-container">
  <div id="dev" class="svc display-yes">
  <p>lorem ipsum1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="it" class="svc">
    <p>lorem ipsum2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="design" class="svc">
    <p>lorem ipsum3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="consult" class="svc">
    <p>lorem ipsum4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:#c2c2c2;">
  <p>
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer, it did solve the problem, the problem now is, in the actual website I'm working on, removing the position relative breaks the next block :/

Comment: Can you provide a snippet with the next block?

Comment: The behavior is like this https://jsfiddle.net/5v86Lpb0/

Comment: I updated my answer. You just needed a container around your absolutely positioned divs.

Answer (score 0):

you have different problems: using position absolute for hidden elements will alway cause display troubles
I suggest to use a parent div with the global size ( and color) and each tab inside are on the same absolute position inside.

Your question is unclear, and I suppose  you expect a waiting for the end of fade out before starting the fade in of the next tab .
so you need to use a transitionend event to detect the fade out finish

I also suggest to use event delegation for all tabs buttons, with the help of data information attribute, that make html code more reliable, and less JS code

so this code: ( with transition = one second for testing)

```js
const tabButtons = document.querySelector('div.tab')
  ,   buttonTabs = document.querySelectorAll('div.tab > button.tablink')
  ,   tabData    = [...document.querySelectorAll('div.svc')].reduce((res,eTab)=>
        {
        res.push( { id:eTab.id, disp:eTab.classList.contains('display-yes'), elm: eTab} )
        return res
        },[])

tabButtons.onclick =e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button.tablink'))   return // ignore others clicks outsides 

  let currentTab = tabData.find(tb=>tb.disp)
    , newTab     = tabData.find(tb=>tb.id===e.target.dataset.tabId)   

  if (newTab.id != currentTab.id )
    {
    currentTab.elm.addEventListener('transitionend',setNewTab)
    currentTab.elm.classList.remove('display-yes')
    currentTab.disp = false

    buttonTabs.forEach(bt=>bt.classList.remove('active'))
    e.target.classList.add('active')
    }
  function setNewTab()
    {
    currentTab.elm.removeEventListener('transitionend',setNewTab)
    newTab.elm.classList.add('display-yes')
    newTab.disp = true
    }
  }
```

```css
#all-svc {
  position:relative;
  width:500px; 
  height:200px;
  background-color:#00488ab5;
  margin-top: 1em;
  }
.svc{
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  }
.display-yes{
  opacity:1;
  }
.tablink{
  background-color:#0000ffb5;
  }
.active{
  background-color:#ff0000b5;  
  }
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablink active" data-tab-id="dev"> Desenvolvimento de software </button> 
  <button class="tablink" data-tab-id="it"> Infraestruturas IT </button> 
  <button class="tablink" data-tab-id="design"> UX / UI Design </button> 
  <button class="tablink" data-tab-id="consult"> Consultoria </button> 
</div>

<div id="all-svc">
  <div id="dev" class="svc display-yes">
    <p>lorem ipsum 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="it" class="svc">
    <p>lorem ipsum 2 lorem ipsum 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="design" class="svc">
    <p>lorem ipsum 3 ipsum 3 lorem 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="consult" class="svc">
    <p>lorem ipsum 4 lorem ipsum ipsum ipsum 4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:#c2c2c2;">
  <p> 
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  </p>
</div>
```